# uitableviewcell no se adapta bien al ipad

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uitableviewcell

Estoy teniendo problemas en la vista del iPad, estoy intentando hacer una tabla en la que cada celda estará formada por un `textLabel` y un botón `UIButton`, cuando lo pruebo en un iphone la vista sale bien, pero cuando lo pruebo con un iPad sale de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *simpleTable = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"simpleTableIdentifier%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTable];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTable];
    }

    Centro_DTO *cen_datos = [[Centro_DTO alloc] init];
    cen_datos = [self.computersCentros objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *currentL = ([Global sharedMySingleton].test);

    if ([currentL isEqualToString:@"es"]) {

        cell.textLabel.text = cen_datos.nombreES;
    } else if ([currentL isEqualToString:@"ca-ES"]) {

        cell.textLabel.text = cen_datos.nombreCA;
    } else if ([currentL isEqualToString:@"en"]) {

        cell.textLabel.text = cen_datos.nombreEN;
    }

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(44/255.0) blue:(82/255.0) alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    UIButton *centroActivo = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    centroActivo.highlighted = NO;

    int orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && orientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)) {
        centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 15.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    } else {
        centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(290.0, 15.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
    }
    centroActivo.tag = indexPath.row;
    [centroActivo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [centroActivo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [centroActivo addTarget:self action:@selector(checkboxSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (cen_datos.activo == 1) {

        [centroActivo setSelected:YES];
    } else {

        [centroActivo setSelected:NO];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:centroActivo];

    return cell;
}
```

y lo que quiero es que se vea de la siguiente forma en el ipad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia de lo que puede ser?

P.D: soy bastante nuevo con el desarrollo en [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues es el tipico ejemplo de autolayout. Tienes que definir su posición con respecto al resto de los ítems. Puedes hacerlo usando un .xib o a mano. El textlabel te lo posiciona correctamente la celda por defecto, pero la imagen la tienes que situar tu. Para hacer eso a mano tienes que:

- Primera cosa, no es necesario que posiciones el botón. Si lo haces te lo dibujara en las coordenadas que le indiques. Crea el centroactivo solo con tamaño, sin posición

  ```
  centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0f, 20.0f);
  ```
- Tienes que poner translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints a NO para poder poner constraints a mano

  ```
  centroActivo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  ```
- Después tienes que añadir centroActivo a la vista (la celda en este caso)
- Por ultimo añades constraints para indicarle donde posicionarlo. Aquí esta la manteca. Tienes que dar las posiciones necesaria para que iOS sepa donde dibujar. En este caso creo que con indicarle que esta a x puntos del margen izquierdo (por ejemplo 15) y que lo centre con respecto la celda seria suficiente.

  ```
  NSlayoutConstraint *trailing = [NSLayoutContraint 
                               constraintWithItem: centroActivo
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem: self.contentView
                               attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                               multiplier: 1.0f
                               constant: 15.f];
  NSlayoutConstraint *center = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centroActivo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                             
                                  toItem:self.contentView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                              multiplier:1 
                                constant:0];


  [self.contentView addConstraint:trailing];
  [self.contentView addConstraint:center];
  ```

Así que las lineas donde con pruebas la orientación y si es iPad las quitaría y solo dejaría el frame del centroActivo
Todo esto fuera:
int orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]statusBarOrientation];

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && orientation != UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)) {
    centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(350.0, 15.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
} else {
    centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(290.0, 15.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
}
```

y solo dejaría el

```
centroActivo.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, .0f, 20.0f, 20.0f);
```

**El TextLabel se solapa**

Pues para este caso hay que hacer algo similar. Indicarle donde tiene que pintarlo
Así pues lo primero es decirle que le vas a tocar las constraints

```
    cell.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Y después al igual que con el centroActivo añadir las constraints. En este caso le vamos a dar una hacia la izquierda de unos 15 puntos, lo vamos a centrar con respecto a la celda y le vamos a decir que tiene que estar a otros 15 puntos de distancia con el centroActivo.

```
    //esto es la derecha, así que se relaciona con centroActivo
    NSlayoutConstraint *trailingText = [NSLayoutContraint 
                         constraintWithItem: cell.textLabel
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                         toItem: centroActivo
                         attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                         multiplier: 1.0f
                         constant: 15.f];
    NSlayoutConstraint *centerText = [NSLayoutConstraint     constraintWithItem:cell.textLabel
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual                                                             
                            toItem:self.contentView
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                        multiplier:1 
                          constant:0];
    //esto es con el margen izquierdo
    NSlayoutConstraint *leadingText = [NSLayoutContraint 
                         constraintWithItem: cell.textLabel
                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                         relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                         toItem: self.contentView
                         attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                         multiplier: 1.0f
                         constant: 15.f];

    [self.contentView addConstraint:leadingText];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:trailingText];
    [self.contentView addConstraint:centerText];
```

Espero que te sirva, el ObjC ya lo tengo un poco olvidado

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo probaré hoy

Comment: He seguido los pasos que me has puesto y ha ido bien, he cambiado las constrains y he puesto esto :  [cell.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:centroActivo attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:cell.contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRightMargin multiplier:1.0f  constant:-15.f]]; El unico problema es que si el texto es muy larga en el Iphone pasa por debajo de la imagen del boton

Comment: Entonces también hay que meterse con constraints del texto.  Cuando tenga unpoco de tiempo te lo pongo. Es un poco laborioso. Yo lo tengo en swift, imagino que en ObjC funcionara igual, pero no lo se. intento probar y te digo @Joacer

Comment: Muchas gracias @spidvmp!!

Answer (score 1):

Esto es debido a no utilizar o utilizar de forma incorrecta `AutoLayout`.
Debes crear unas constraints que dejen fijo el checkbox a la derecha. Después, la constraint derecha de la `UILabel` debe estar siempre "pegada" al lado izquierdo del checkbox.

Es complicado de explicar por aquí, pero básicamente es un problema de `AutoLayout`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo probaré hoy